# Color Library AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, colors

Does a library exist for AS3 that performs color conversions and transitions such as converting a hex with alpha component to a ColorTransform?

I'm basically looking for a wrapper around the Color classes of a pure AS3 project to make dealing with them more elegant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Colorjizz](http://code.google.com/p/colorjizz/) is the library for you!

Comment: The library seems quite legit, but WTF were they thinking when they chose its name...

Comment: It was just a bit of fun :) If anyone finds any bugs please report them to me on gcode! thanks